# When a condition is met in a pandas column return the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with around 1000 rows. here's a made up version which applies to my issue. If i wanted to filter out the Trade IDs when the trade quantity was over 10 this would leave single trade ID's (for instance the second 523 would drop and leave the first one).

I understand I need to lookup through Trade Quantity column and find values which are < 10 then return the trade id from that row, then drop rows where the trade id matches.

I understand this is incorrect, but this is what I had before.

```
df.drop(df[df['Trade Quantity'] < 10], inplace =True
```

Could an iloc statement work? and return the index

[image: Trade Data]

Ideally the dataframe would be updated so that its left with just the Trade ID 487, my code has no issue for the last two rows as both have a trade quantity under 10 but the issues lies in the case when one quantity is above the threshold and one is below. See below image for desired output.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're generally in the right direction. To allow others to reproduce your challenge and propose a solution, could you please include the input dataframe **as text** in your question - as well as the expected output?

Comment: In your case, ``drop`` is redundant try this ``df[df['Trade Quantity'] > 10]``

Comment: sorry updated the question so hopefully makes more sense what im trying to do! thanks for any help

Comment: You'd like to be left with trade IDs that are over 10 for all their rows?

Comment: Yes but not exactly, my issue is with the first row you see that trade id has one quantity over 10 and one below 10. I want Trade ID's removed if only one side is over 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
unique_ids = df.loc[df['Trade Quantity'] < 10, 'Trade ID'].unique()

df = df[~df['Trade ID'].isin(unique_ids)]
```

Comment: This wants to be `df = df[~df['Trade ID'].isin(unique_ids)]`

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty, but I think this may do what you're after? Removes any entries where there is only one row with the corresponding Trade ID

```
df.drop(df[(df["Trade Quantity"] < 10)].index, inplace = True)

for each in set(df["Trade ID"]):
    if len(df[(df["Trade ID"]) == each]) < 2:
        df.drop(df[(df["Trade ID"] == each)].index, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly standard way to do that using groupby / transform:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"trade_id": [523, 523, 487, 487, 367, 367], 
              "buy_or_sell": ["b", "s", "b", "s", "b", "s"], 
              "quantity" : [15, 5, 13, 13, 4, 4]}) 

df["min_quantity"] = df.groupby("trade_id")["quantity"].transform(min)
df[df.min_quantity > 10]
```

The output is:

```
   trade_id buy_or_sell  quantity  min_quantity
2       487           b        13            13
3       487           s        13            13
```